# Error with GWT Stockwatcher tutorial

Tags: gwt

I am working through the GWT tutorial. I get through step 3 and when I go to run it I get an error with the web browser that says, "Plugin failed to connect to host mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997"

In the eclipse development mode there are two errors one with finding entry point classes that says,"unable to find type 'com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.Stockwatcher'" And another error that says, "failed to load module stockwatcher from user agent.

Any ideas? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes compiling (click the red G toolbox icon) can give extra error information like the specific line number that's causing the failure.  Anything in this case?

Comment: I don't see this icon anywhere?

Comment: Have you installed the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_UnableToFindModuleInHosted) can help.

I hope so.